# Parse XML subtitle and convert into .srt plain text

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an XML document as follow:

```
<document id="5509769">
  <s id="1">
    <time id="T1S" value="00:00:07,910" />
    <w alternative="Ciske" id="1.1">CISKE</w>
    <w id="1.2">Die</w>
    <w alternative="rot" id="1.3">ROT</w>
    <time id="T1E" value="00:00:10,910" />
  </s>
  <s id="2">
    <time id="T2S" value="00:00:12,320" />
    <w id="2.1">Almal</w>
    <w id="2.2">kan</w>
    <w id="2.3">maar</w>
    <w id="2.4">die</w>
    <w id="2.5">Cholera</w>
    <w id="2.6">kry</w>
    <w id="2.7">,</w>
    <time id="T2E" value="00:00:15,690" />
    <time id="T3S" value="00:00:15,750" />
    <w id="2.8">en</w>
    <w id="2.9">vir</w>
    <w id="2.10">my</w>
    <w id="2.11">part</w>
    <w id="2.12">kan</w>
    <w id="2.13">almal</w>
    <w id="2.14">doodgaan</w>
    <w id="2.15">.</w>
    <time id="T3E" value="00:00:18,890" />
  </s>
  <s id="3">
    <time id="T4S" value="00:00:18,960" />
    <w id="3.1">Ek</w>
    <w id="3.2">het</w>
    <w id="3.3">nie</w>
    <w id="3.4">lus</w>
    <w id="3.5">om</w>
    <w id="3.6">te</w>
    <w id="3.7">leer</w>
    <w id="3.8">nie</w>
    <w id="3.9">.</w>
    <time id="T4E" value="00:00:22,490" />
   </s>
</document>
```

And I would like to convert this into a .srt plain text file using Linq.

For exemple, the ouput for this XML node would be:

```
1
00:00:07,910 --> 00:00:10,910
CISKE Die ROT

2
00:00:12,320 --> 00:00:18,890
Almal kan maar die Cholera kry, en vir my part kan almal doodgaan.

3
00:00:18,960 --> 00:00:22,490
Ek het nie lus om te leer nie.
```

I have tried this:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(XML);
using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc))
{
   nodeReader.MoveToContent();
   XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);            
   List<dynamic> elements =
   (
      from item in xdoc.Descendants("s")
      select new
      {
         Begin = (item.FirstNode as XElement).LastAttribute.Value,
         Last = (item.LastNode as XElement).LastAttribute.Value
      }
   ).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

But I failed retrieving all w node values.

Comment: Aham, And..what it is exactly the problem you have? I mean, what have you tried so far.

Comment: Which bit is failing exactly? The retrieval of the end time?

Comment: I've tested this code and returned what expected. The only thing is XML should be the path name for the XML file, not the content of the file.

Comment: See here for more examples: https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/tree/master/src/libse/SubtitleFormats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the **w** element values by getting all the **w** descendants from the parent **item**.

As the code below shows, the **NodeValuesInArray** is returned as an array of values which you can iterate through later.

Also, I've included a space separated version of the values (**NodeValuesCommaSeparated**) which can be used directly for display if that's more suitable.

```
using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc))
{
    nodeReader.MoveToContent();
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);
    List<dynamic> elements =
    (
        from item in xdoc.Descendants("s")
        select new
        {
            Begin = (item.FirstNode as XElement).LastAttribute.Value,
            Last = (item.LastNode as XElement).LastAttribute.Value,
            NodeValuesInArray = item.Descendants("w").Select(q => q.Value).ToArray(),
            NodeValuesCommaSeparated = string.Join(" ", item.Descendants("w").Select(q => q.Value).ToArray())
        }
    ).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```